# Protractor - Cannot read property '$$testability' of undefined

Tags: protractor

I am getting an error which reads:

```
"Error while waiting for Protractor to synce with the page: "Cannot read property '$$testability' of undefined"
```

Below is my test.

```
describe('On the MyMoments page', function(){  

    beforeEach(function() {
        var editLocationText = 'Location';

        browser.driver.get('http://192.168.0.6:8100/#/page1/myMoments');
    });

    it('The edit button should work', function() {
        browser.driver.get('http://192.168.0.6:8100/#/page1/myMoments').then(function() {
            // browser.waitForAngular();
            browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {

            });
        });


    });
});
```

This is my config file:

```
exports.config = {  
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {                
            args: ['--disable-web-security']
        } 
    },
    baseUrl: 'http://192.168.0.6:8100',
    specs: [
    '*.test.js'
    ],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        isVerbose: true,
    }
};
```

I don't think this is something to do with my test since my test is incredibly simple.  Has anybody run into this issue before?  I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Downgraded my Protractor version all the way to 4.0.14 in order to fix this error.  Now i'm getting:

```
"Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability/http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/test"
```

If anyone knows what this is or how to resolve this, let me know!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in Protractor, see [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4233). As mentioned in the issue this is because browser.angularAppRoot() is expected to return the current value of app root if a value isn't passed to it, but currently returns undefined.
A new release is coming that should fix this issue.

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there anyway for a temporary fix?  Are my Protractor tests just broken until they come out with this patch?

Comment: Which version of Protractor are you using? Maybe you can downgrade a version (patch or minor version)

Comment: I went all the way to version 4.0.14 and I started getting "Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability/http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/test"

Comment: Ironically I just upgraded Protractor and Selenium to fix a bug with the latest Firefox. It's getting to be impossible to find the right combination to keep this thing running..

Comment: The Protractor bug has been fixed in 5.1.2.  If you're still getting this error, it is probably due to a different underlying problem causing your page to be blank at the time when Protractor sees it.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's sometimes caused by documents without an html tag in the root, "Cannot read property '$$testability' of undefined" is more likely to manifest as a symptom of another error that prevented the page from loading, or any interaction with a page that isn't loaded for whatever reason.

Try using a browser.sleep above the line that is throwing the error, to give the page time to load.

A browser.ExpectedConditions clause which is intended to wait for a specific condition can throw this error if the page is not ready for protractor.

**Sometimes, hard coded sleeps can not be avoided.**

To diagnose and fix it,

- Place browser.enterRepl(); into the code just before the line
  that seems to be throwing the $$testability error.
- If the $$testability error still gets thrown, then move browser.enterRepl(); up a few lines
- Each time enterRepl() gets triggered without the $$testability error, then move browser.enterRepl(); down one line
- Finally, when enterRepl is moved to the line directly below the line causing the error, you may now see a different error message which is more meaningful.
- Place a browser.sleep() or other code to fix your specific issue just prior to the line causing that error.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the browser from chrome to firefox worked for me.

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine',
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'firefox'
},
specs: ['login-spec.js']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with an Angular hybrid app.
In my case the issue was fixed after removing,

```
rootElement: 'myRootElement'
```

from the config.