# Cannot read property $$testability of undefined - No Ng-app directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Our development site had recently updated to Angular 4.X. As ng-app no longer exists in Angular, it has been removed in angularJS.
Due to this change, there is no more data-ng-app directive in the code base .

Before upgrade
[The tests are working fine with this code, where ng-App is present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hLLs.jpg)

After upgrade
[Throws error 'Cannot read property $$testability of undefined' as ng-App is not present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh0hX.jpg)

From other similar SO posts, a specific rootElement has to be provided in conf file; however, could someone please me know how to deal this situation (as ng-App is NOT available)

Comment: Clarification: are you upgrading from AngularJS to Angular? For your Protractor test, what does your configuration look like. What is the error and stack trace?

Comment: @cnishina Please find the below for config and error/stack trace.      
 Config https://pastebin.com/EzNUhaXN   / Error/stack trace   https://pastebin.com/1H0YaprM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using protractor with ng-upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006259/using-protractor-with-ng-upgrade)

Comment: Closer duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882242/protractor-cannot-read-property-testability-of-undefined