# Protractor example test fails when running from command line. cannot read property '$$testability' of unefined

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, configuration, protractor, automated-tests

**Config file**

this is my conf.js file

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
 directConnect: true,

 // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

**Example Spec.js**
is there anything wrong with the code here should i add some type of wait time

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');

    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });

  describe('todo list', function() {
    var todoList;

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

      todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    });

    it('should list todos', function() {
      expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(2);
      expect(todoList.get(1).getText()).toEqual('build an AngularJS app');
    });

    it('should add a todo', function() {
      var addTodo = element(by.model('todoList.todoText'));
      var addButton = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));

      addTodo.sendKeys('write a protractor test');
      addButton.click();

      expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
      expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write a protractor test');
    });
  });
});
```

**Error Code**

this is the error I am getting

[image]
[image]

This seems to be a common issue with protractor if any one can assist me with a fix to get this test running please do

Thanks 
Mike,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protractor - Cannot read property '$$testability' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882242/protractor-cannot-read-property-testability-of-undefined)

Comment: nah thats not helping me at all my pages loads but for some reason its not entering the name. i did all the steps to install correctly from the protractor website. im just stuck here

Comment: What version of Protractor are you using?